# Rspec FactoryGirl with has_many through got MissingAttributeError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rspec, factory-bot

I have `has_many through` relations:

Poll that `has_many` votee (User) through History:

```
has_many :polls_through_history, through: :history, class_name: "Poll", foreign_key: "poll_id", source: :poll
```

and

User that `has_many` voted (Poll) through History

```
has_many :users_through_history, through: :history, class_name: "User", foreign_key: 'user_id', source: :user
```

**the History model:**

```
class History < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :poll
  has_one :choice
end
```

**history spec:**

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe History, type: :model do
  before do  
    @poll_owner = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    @voter = FactoryGirl.create(:user) 
    @poll = FactoryGirl.create(:poll, user: @poll_owner)
    @choice = @poll.choices[0]
    @history = FactoryGirl.create(:history, user: @voter, poll: @poll, choice: @choice) 
  end

  subject { @history }

  it { should respond_to(:user_id) }
  it { should respond_to(:poll_id) }
  it { should respond_to(:choice_id) }

  it { should belong_to(:user) }
  it { should belong_to(:poll) }
  it { should have_one(:choice) }
end
```

I always get following error for all test cases:

```
Failure/Error: @history = FactoryGirl.create(:history, user: @voter, poll: @poll, choice: @choice)
 ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError:
   can't write unknown attribute `history_id`
```

Whats wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems that it is actually a problem between history and choice (only there rails would expect `history_id` column). Do you have such a column in `choices` table?

Comment: @BroiSatse, you are correct, I replace the `choice` with `choice_id`, and remove the `has_one :choice` in the model. And its works.

Btw, but if I add `history_id` to the choice table, it will not make sense, because a single choice can be selected by many voter/user isn't it?

Comment: I don't know what those models are to represent so it is cannot help you here. :)

Comment: if you want you can make that as an answers, then I will mark as correct answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error message, this is a problem with association between history and choice model -  you have no `history_id` column on `choice`. As you mentioned, having such a column wouldn't have much sense in your case, so you should change `has_one` to `belongs_to` association.

Comment: his solution is actually correct. But in my case, it was my fault in table relation, it should be History `belongs_to :choice` and Choice `has_many :histories`. instead of History `has_one :choice`.

Comment: Eh, it happens for a second time this week. This solution was for another question, no idea how i got them wrong. need to find what I posted there)